Link multiple pdf files into excel rows at the same timing using VBA
I have excel files where in column A I have the exact names of PDFs that are in a PDF subfolder in the same folder as the excel file. I am trying to hyperlink these PDFs in excel using visual basic. I know how to do it individually but there are usually ~30 rows of PDFs I am trying to link. I am looking for guidance on how to come up with this code not knowing visual basic. I've attached an example of what the excel file would look like and an example of the folder containing the pdf folder and excel file for visual reference.

I don't know VB but have tried to google/ search stack overflow for this but haven't had much luck finding guidance on this!
I tried to use this code: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-auto-hyperlink-a-pdf-file-from-a-folder-based-on-cell-value.958019/
but nothing happens when I push play:
Sub AddHypaerlinks()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myPath As String, fileName As String


myPath = "C:\Users\dchaney\Documents\" 'SET TO WHERE THE FILES ARE LOCATED
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow

    fileName = myPath & Range("A" & i).Value & "*.pdf"
    
    If Len(Dir(fileName)) <> 0 Then 'IF THE FILE EXISTS THEN
    
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A" & i), myPath & Dir(fileName)
    
    End If
    
Next

End Sub


ThisWorkbook.Path gives you the location where your folder is.  Dir() can be used to check the existence of a file in that folder.  Record a macro while inserting a link to get the syntax you need for that part.  Try to make a start, and post back with your code and an explanation of exactly what's not working, and folks here will help.  Typically we don't write code from scratch though.

Thank you Tim! I have recorded a macro of linking a single pdf. I tried to make it work in a module in visual basic but it didn't quite work. this is what I recorded: function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Apply hyperlink to range A2 on selectedSheet}
selectedSheet.getRange("A2").setHyperlink({textToDisplay: "PDF1.pdf", address: "PDFs\PDF1.pdf"});
}

... I also found this code online but it didnt do anything when I added it (I made sure to put the correct path in)... Sub AddHypaerlinks()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myPath As String, fileName As String
myPath = "C: PATH " 'SET TO WHERE THE FILES ARE LOCATED
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow
fileName = myPath & Range("A" & i).Value & "*.pdf"

If Len(Dir(fileName)) <> 0 Then 'IF THE FILE EXISTS THEN

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A" & i), myPath & Dir(fileName)

End If

Next
End Sub

myPath is missing a \ at the end  Also do not include the * in Dir() if you're looking for exact matches.

Have you change the value of mypath  in the code to the correct folder?

@TimWilliams I was able to remove the Dir information without getting an error but adding a \ anywhere in the file is giving me an error. if i add a \ around the last mention of myPath it said compile error: expected: expression.. below is what I have revised to:

Sub AddHyperlinks()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myPath As String, fileName As String
myPath = "R:\KTR\Mill Ticket Information\Archive\Link PDFs\PDFs" 'SET TO WHERE THE FILES ARE LOCATED
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow
fileName = myPath & Range("A" & i).Value & "*.pdf"

If Len(fileName) <> 0 Then 'IF THE FILE EXISTS THEN

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A" & i), myPath

End If

Next
End Sub

Please use the edit link below your post if you want to add/edit code: it's unreadable in a comment.

This works for me:
Sub AddHyperlinks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, pdf As String, i As Long
    Dim pdfPath As String
    
    pdfPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDFs\" 'your folder of PDF
    '...or use a fixed path
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'always best to use a worksheet reference 
    
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        pdf = Trim(ws.Range("A" & i).Value) 'in case of extra spaces...

        If Len(Dir(pdfPath & pdf)) > 0 Then 'IF THE FILE EXISTS THEN
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A" & i), _
                              Address:=pdfPath & pdf, _
                              TextToDisplay:=pdf
        End If
    Next

End Sub


I will try that! I seem to have lost the edited code without the *in Dir(). Thank you for your help with this issue!
